# text disappears when mouse moved

Tags: html, css

When I move my mouse over the image the text does pop up, but when I move my mouse after that it disappears. I have no idea why that is happening, and it's really frustrating. Does anyone have any clue as to what might be happening here?

```css
.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
}
.imgDescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2D2D2D;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="cows.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="hvr-bounce-to-right">
    <div class="imgWrap">
      <p class="imgDescription">This is some hovertext</p>
      <img class="cow" src="cow.jpg" alt="cow">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Document

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
}
.imgDescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
  -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
  */
}
.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2D2D2D;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your selector.

Instead of this:

```
.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Use this:

```
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
}
.imgWrap img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.imgDescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
  -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
  */
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2D2D2D;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="hvr-bounce-to-right">
  <div class="imgWrap">
    <p class="imgDescription">This is some hovertext</p>
    <img class="cow" src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/200?image=0" alt="cow">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Explanation:**

Because you are using a pseudoelement `::before` as an overlay and giving it a value of `1` in its `z-index` property, it will cover the other elements in the stack context of your parent element `.hvr-bounce-to-right`.

You could see it this way. When you hover `.hvr-bounce-to-right` element, you can't get pass through the pseudoelement, so you are not really hovering `.imgWrap`, but the pseudoelement.

Since `.hvr-bounce-to-right` is the one being hovered, you can use that as your selector and solve the issue.

---

**Notes:**

- To remove the unwanted space under the `<img>` element, use
  `vertical-align: middle;`.

This comment:

```
 /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
  -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
  */
```

is wrong, you cannot use `transition` with properties like `visibility` which have a binary setting. It just switches between two states (visible/hidden), not between values like `opacity`, which can go from `0` to `1`. The correct value there is:

```
transition: opacity 0.2s;
```

---

**EDIT:**

> I'm trying to align my text within that hover element, I want it to be
>   centered but cannot seem to think of a way to do this. Any
>   suggestions?

Use the `transform` translate way of centering both vertical and horizontal:

```
el {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
}
.imgWrap img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.imgDescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  */
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2D2D2D;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="hvr-bounce-to-right">
  <div class="imgWrap">
    <p class="imgDescription">This is some hovertext</p>
    <img class="cow" src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/200?image=0" alt="cow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the question. One more question for you though, now I'm trying to align my text within that hover element, I want it to be centered but cannot seem to think of a way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It's a `z-index` issue.

Try

```
.imgDescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
  -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
  */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
}
.imgDescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
  -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
  */
  z-index: 1;
}
.imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2D2D2D;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="hvr-bounce-to-right">
  <div class="imgWrap">
    <p class="imgDescription">This is some hovertext</p>
    <img class="cow" src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/200?image=0" alt="cow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this seems to solve the issue, when you hover on top of the `.imgDescription` `margin` this does not work. He should change his selector.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove these two lines

```
Visibility: hidden;
```

and

```
Visibility: visible;
```